# Safari rendering issue when changing position:fixed to position:relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I am developing, just for fun, a jQuery plugin that reveals elements from a "stack" as you scroll down the page.

Github repo is here - https://github.com/JayBizzle/Reveal

Demo is here - http://jaybizzle.github.io/Reveal/

Everything works great in Chrome, but when testing in Safari I am seeing some weird rendering issues.

If you view the demo in Safari and scroll down fairly quickly, you will notice white gaps appearing between the coloured DIVs.

Even stranger is, if you then inspect one of the out of position DIVs, the inspector highlights the DIV in the correct position. Also, if whilst your in the inspector, you change one of the elements CSS attributes, like adding a border, the page gets redrawn and the element appears in the correct position.

Anyone got any ideas if this is a Safari bug, or something i can overcome with some little known CSS?

Comment: Yeah, although I noticed it maybe isn't quite as bad in FireFox. Very strange *bug* though

Comment: What I would do is to delay the execution of the `scroll` and `resize` events until they are completed like http://jsfiddle.net/nRCX9/

Comment: look what happens if events are not delayed (scroll the window) http://jsfiddle.net/wR5j4/ and when they are http://jsfiddle.net/wR5j4/1/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
My workaround was giving position static first and then relative with a bit of delay.

```
    $(elem).css('position', 'static');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(elem).css('position', 'relative');
    }, 1);
```